# jScroll pane function ceases when I use "set text of container" onClick of button to change content of div ID

Tags: javascript, text, set, containers, jscrollpane

This has to be possible but my knowledge of javascript is very limited.

I have one DIV ID container of a fixed size, and I want people to be able to click each button and the content within that container changes. The DIV ID has jScroll function so that it creates a stylized scrollbar.

When I set use "Set Text of Container" behavior, everything places correctly and the buttons work but the jScroll does not work so the content overflow is simply cut off.

How do I fix this? Do I need to use the Call Javascript function?

EDIT:
I know that the answer to my problem is on their website but there are no tutorials or how-to instructions for people who are unfamiliar with javascript, API, etc. I don't understand where to place the code or even what code to add to make this work. Could you give me more detailed instructions on how to .reinitialise the jScroll javascript on a DIV ID - I'm using Dreamweaver, and "Set Text of Container" somehow voids the jScroll javascript for that container.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling .reinitialise(); on the jScroll element

I found it [here](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/dynamic_content.html)

Take a look at this example:

```
$(function()
{
    /* settings for the jsp */
    var settings = {
        showArrows: true
    };

    /* a handle to the element in the DOM */
    var pane = $('.scroll-pane');

    /* initiate the plugin and create the jsp */
    pane.jScrollPane(settings);

    /* get a handle to the jScrollPanes data */
    var api = pane.data('jsp');
    var i = 1;

    /* Every second add some new content by calling this function */
    setInterval(
        function()
        {
            /* get a handle to the jsp content and append a paragraph with some text to it */
            api.getContentPane().append(
                $('<p />').text('This is paragraph number ' + i++)
            );

            /* we could call "pane.jScrollPane(settings)" again but it is
              more convenient to call via the API as then the original
              settings we passed in are automatically remembered.
            */
            api.reinitialise();
        },
        1000
    );
});
```

Alternatively you can just pass in autoReinitialise: true in the settings and then you dont have to call api.reinitialise(); at a [cost](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/settings.html#autoReinitialise)